# Remotely access data on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, 18.04, samba, file-server

How might I be able to set up Ubuntu Server so that multiple people can access their own personal directory that only they would know the password for from anywhere in the world? Each person’s directory needs to be private and inaccessible by all other users, including me (the administrator) for obvious security reasons. I have heard of something called Samba File Server, but I don’t know how well people will be able to access their directories remotely.

Comment: Samba is more suitable for a local network. For anywhere in the world, use ssh.

Comment: Yes, but many of the people who will use the storage either don’t have experience with ssh or don’t run a UNIX machine. Also, I’m not trying to give them access to the system, I just the users to be able to mount their directory on their computer and access all their data from there, or some other kind of seamless access to their directory. From my understanding, ssh gives you access to the login on the server. The users could then log in, but how do I make it so that they can only access their private directory and be able to move data to and from that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at OwnCloud. It's like an open source DropBox, hosted on your own premises. Like DropBox, it has sync clients for most common platforms.

https://owncloud.org/features/

Comment: Thank you. I noticed you’re a now contributor, so welcome to the community